# How can I verify the sign of product of 3 numbers without multiplying them?

Tags: java

I have an exercise that sounds like this :

> Calculate the sign of the product of 3 numbers:
>
> - Read 3 **floating-point numbers**
> - Print the sign of the product of the entered 3 numbers: **positive**,
>     **negative** or **zero**
>
> Try to do this **without multiplying the 3 numbers**

I tried this way :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

       double a = in.nextDouble();
       double b = in.nextDouble();
       double c = in.nextDouble();


       switch(){
          case a:
          case b:
          case c:
             if (a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0){
                System.out.printf("positive");
             }else if ( a > 0 && b < 0 && c > 0){
                System.out.printf("negative");
             }else if ( a > 0 && b > 0 && c < 0){
                System.out.printf("negative");
             }else if ( a < 0 && b > 0 && c > 0){
                System.out.printf("negative");
             }else if ( a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0){
                System.out.printf("zero");
             }
       }


}
```

}

What condition should I put in switch's brackets in order to make this program work assuming that the `if`, `else if` conditions are correct?

And if they're not , what can I possibly to , with switch case , in order to solve this exercise succesfully?

My **input** to be for example :

```
2
3
-1
```

My **output**:

```
negative
```

Comment: if any number is zero, the result will be zero, not only if all 3 are zero (and/or mismatch)

Comment: Ohh , you are right :) Thank you !

Comment: But what condition should I put in switch's brackets in order to make it work ?

Comment: not sure why the `switch`, but maybe go by [Govinda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60248423/85421), adapted to use `switch`, something like start count with `-1` if **any** value is zero (`a` **or** `b` **or** `c` is zero), otherwise with the count of negative numbers, then `switch` on `-1`, `0`, `1`, `2`, or `3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Considering all 3 numbers are non-zero**

If you have 1 or 3 negative numbers, the product will be negative. Otherwise, the product will be positive.

```
int count = 0;
if(a < 0)
    count++;
if(b < 0)
    count++;
if(c < 0)
    count++;

if(count % 2 == 1)
    System.out.println("Negative");
else
    System.out.println("Positive");
```